# How to map parquet record (json) to case class using alpakka

Tags: scala, parquet, akka-stream, alpakka

I have the data that saved in parquet file as json e.g
{"name":"john", "age":23.5}
I want to convert it to

`case class Person(name: String, age: Double)` so I can use pattern matching in my actor.
This is what I got so far:

```
val reader: ParquetReader[GenericRecord] =  AvroParquetReader.builder[GenericRecord](filePath).withConf(conf).build()

val source: Source[GenericRecord, NotUsed] = AvroParquetSource(reader)
  source.ask[WorkerAck](28)(workerActor)
```

I tried to replace the `GenericRecord` with `Person` but I got the following error:

```
inferred type arguments [com.common.Person] do not conform to method apply's type parameter bounds [T <: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord]
  val source: Source[Person, NotUsed] = AvroParquetSource(reader)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two options

1. Use Avro code generator to generate the code for the Person DTO class. This will create a Person class that inherits from generic record. See  this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-apache-avro)
2. Add an actor that converts GenericRecord instances to Person:

```
Person((String)record.get("name"), (Double)record.get("age"))
```

Comment: Thanks, I did manage to do it with mapping i.e `source.map{ record => Person(record.get("name"), record.get("age").toString.toDouble)`

Comment: A little note... cast with (Type) is a Java thing. In Scala you have to use .asInstanceOf[Type]